# Static html export fails 'Error: Unsupported Server Component type: {...}'

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've got this error when trying to export a next js blog page to static html.

I'm trying to get the basic html (+tailwind) page structure from this [blog template](https://github.com/timlrx/tailwind-nextjs-starter-blog).

Following the instructions on the next js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports) I've changed `module.exports` in `next.config.js` to this

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
 
  // Optional: Change links `/me` -> `/me/` and emit `/me.html` -> `/me/index.html`
  // trailingSlash: true,
 
  // Optional: Prevent automatic `/me` -> `/me/`, instead preserve `href`
  // skipTrailingSlashRedirect: true,
 
  // Optional: Change the output directory `out` -> `dist`
  // distDir: 'dist',
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig
```

where previously, it was

```
/**
 * @type {import('next/dist/next-server/server/config').NextConfig}
 **/
module.exports = () => {
  const plugins = [withContentlayer, withBundleAnalyzer]
  return plugins.reduce((acc, next) => next(acc), {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    pageExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
    eslint: {
      dirs: ['app', 'components', 'layouts', 'scripts'],
    },
    images: {
      remotePatterns: [
        {
          protocol: 'https',
          hostname: 'picsum.photos',
        },
      ],
    },
    async headers() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/(.*)',
          headers: securityHeaders,
        },
      ]
    },
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      })

      return config
    },
  })
}
```

When I try to export, I get this error:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/tags/code". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Unsupported Server Component type: {...}
    at em (/Users/charlie/python_projects/tailwind_blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:129087)
    at /Users/charlie/python_projects/tailwind_blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:140081
    at Object.toJSON (/Users/charlie/python_projects/tailwind_blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:143659)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at eE (/Users/charlie/python_projects/tailwind_blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:132044)
    at eR (/Users/charlie/python_projects/tailwind_blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:132487)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/charlie/python_projects/tailwind_blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:129267)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
   Generating static pages (21/43) [==  ]
```

Is there a way to change the server component type to get past this error? Is exporting a static html file even possible with the way the project is set up?

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found was to host the server locally and save the html webpage produced.